# In objective-c is it possible to set up OS-level account validation like Twitter, Facebook and Vimeo?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm working on an iPhone app that is logging into a webservice and it's been asked of me to get the account login management into the settings page (i.e. next to Twitter, Facebook and Vimeo). From what I've been reading about the accounts framework, it appears that only those few companies have that ability.

I currently have it set up and working asking for login info periodically and polling the webservice for validation, but we're trying to move toward supporting moderately offline use, which means we need to have some sort of account info managed on the phone itself.

Can I use the built-in account framework for our own login credentials or is that not something that's available to a regular dev and I'll have to look for another way to do it on my own? Is that something that the keychain would be better for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the keychain to securely store the users credentials is a good idea to start.

If I am understanding your question about a "built-in account framework", I don't believe there is a local framework for account management on the device itself that I am aware of that would be useful in this circumstance.

I've had to build an app that needed to authenticate to a web service that also needed to have some offline access. I ended up recording the validated authentication date and time in the NSUserDefaults and would let the user use the app for a 48 hours period before they had to re-authenticate. Their data was queued locally and when they had online access again, I would re-authenticate and then sync the data. Not the most elegant solution but it fit the project.

I used AFNetworking (http://afnetworking.com) to track the changes in network access and used to blocks to respond to the changes.

Comment: Cool, sounds like I was on the right track, then. About the framework, I was talking about [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Accounts/Reference/AccountsFrameworkRef/_index.html). I've heard a lot about AFNetworking and ASIHTTPRequest, I've got both of those open and am looking those over to see how they'll work into the project.

Comment: I have not come across the Accounts Framework until now so thanks for pointing that out. Looks like there would be a value in that framework if you were going to use the account across multiple apps. Since they want you to manage the account in some local settings, the keychain sounds like the way to go to me. I just went back and re-read your original post about the client request and I'm not sure if you do have access to that account settings area... now I'm curious.

Comment: Just found this on the Apple dev site: "The Accounts framework (Accounts.framework) provides a single sign-on model for certain user accounts. Single sign-on improves the user experience by eliminating the need to prompt the user separately for multiple accounts. It also simplifies the development model for you by managing the account authorization process for your app. You use this framework in conjunction with the Social framework." Doesn't sound like the Accounts Framework is something you'd want in this case...

Comment: I think I was just over-complicating it by trying to find built-in functions to do what I was looking for. Thanks for the nudge back toward sanity.